# MySQL: Calculated Column Based on Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, case, between

How does one create a calculated column that yields the value of 1 if a date falls within 2015, else 0?

I spent yesterday googling, and searching StackOverflow, for solutions to no avail. From what I learned about CASE WHEN, BETWEEN, and CAST, I put together the below SQL script.

However, the below (truncated) script yields all 0's, despite having corresponding Prescreen dates in 2015, 2016, and even dates of 0000-00-00, as follows:
[image]

```
SELECT 
table_r.R_Number,
table_c.ref_num,
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(table_c.Prescreen, '%d-%b-%y')) AS Prescreen,
CASE
    WHEN Prescreen BETWEEN CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-12-31' AS DATE) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS YTD2015_Prescreen,
table_r.Region,
FROM
table_c
    INNER JOIN
table_r ON table_c.R_Number = table_r.R_Number
WHERE
table_c.Int <> ''
;
```

I humbly ask you to lend me your genius.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT 
    table_r.R_Number,
    table_c.ref_num,
    STR_TO_DATE(table_c.Prescreen,'%d-%b-%y') AS Prescreen,
    CASE
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(table_c.Prescreen,'%d-%b-%y')  BETWEEN CAST('20150101'AS DATE) AND CAST('20151231' AS DATE) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS YTD2015_Prescreen,
    table_r.Region,
    FROM
    table_c
        INNER JOIN
    table_r ON table_c.R_Number = table_r.R_Number
    WHERE
    table_c.Int <> ''
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response, Kamran.

I intentionally used "%b" for date formatting (e.g. Jan to 01) per the MySQL reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

For good measure, I tried "%m" anyway.  Unfortunately, all the dates became "0000-00-00" or NULL.

I look forward to more ideas.  :)

Comment: @DataBender what do you get in the table_c.Prescreen column without the conversion

Comment: Without the STR_TO_DATE conversion, I get "9-Sep-15".

Comment: Looks like it works when you are not wrapping the STR_TO_DATE() in the DATE() I just had a few tries on SQL fiddle and it worked fine.

Comment: @DataBender looks like its working now, also you have to wrap your prescreen field within the CASE satement as I have done or it will always return 0. Hope this helps

Comment: Success!  Thank you, @KamranFarzami !  =)

Comment: sometimes being OCD helps ;)